# Why do I get a `DuplicateChunk` decoding error when using the image crate?

Tags: image, rust, format

I'm using [image](https://crates.io/crates/image) to open and read images in Rust.
I used the Windows Snipping tool to save a screenshot as an image, and tried opening that

```rust
let image_path = "C:/Users/mason/rust-projects/image-test/image.png";
let image = image::open(image_path).unwrap();
let _ = image;
```

But I get the error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Decoding(DecodingError { format: Exact(Png), underlying: Some(Format(FormatError { inner: DuplicateChunk { kind: ChunkType { type: gAMA, critical: false, private: false, reserved: false, safecopy: false } } })) })', src\main.rs:82:12
stack backtrace:
   0: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
             at /rustc/30b3f35c420694a4f24e5a4df00f06073f4f3a37\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:584
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/30b3f35c420694a4f24e5a4df00f06073f4f3a37\/library\core\src\panicking.rs:143
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/30b3f35c420694a4f24e5a4df00f06073f4f3a37\/library\core\src\result.rs:1749
   3: enum$<core::result::Result<enum$<image::dynimage::DynamicImage>,enum$<image::error::ImageError> > >::unwrap<enum$<image::dynimage::DynamicImage>,enum$<image::error::ImageError> >
             at /rustc/30b3f35c420694a4f24e5a4df00f06073f4f3a37\library\core\src\result.rs:1065
   4: image_test::main
             at .\src\main.rs:3
   5: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once<void (*)(),tuple$<> >
             at /rustc/30b3f35c420694a4f24e5a4df00f06073f4f3a37\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:227
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\image-test.exe` (exit code: 101)

Process finished with exit code 101
```

If I try opening a photo I took with my phone, it works fine.
How can I open the screenshot in rust?

Comment: The error says `DuplicateChunk ... gAMA` and [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter10.html) says *"There can be only one gAMA chunk"*. So it looks like your PNG is malformed, I do not see multiple `gAMA` chunks when using the Windows Snipping Tool myself.

Comment: @kmdreko is there a way that I can remove the duplicated gAMA chunk?

Comment: I guess you can open up the file in a hex editor, find one of the places it says "gAMA", and remove it and the trailing 12 bytes. But you should also see if this is a systemic problem, i.e. take another snip and see if it has the same issue.

Comment: @kmdreko I created another snippet and got the same results. I also opened the file in a hex editor, but I only found one match for `gAMA`. I still tried removing the `gAMA` and the trailing 12 bytes. I can no longer open the image in Photos, and trying to open it in rust gives the error: `thread 'main' panicked at 'called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: IoError(Error { kind: UnexpectedEof, message: "failed to fill whole buffer" })'`

Comment: I was actually wrong, you should've removed the `gAMA`, the preceeding 4 bytes, and the trailing 8 bytes. My bad.

Comment: Looking around, it appears there is a (freshly) open issue for this [DuplicateChunk error for image with sRGB chunk preceding gAMA chunk](https://github.com/image-rs/image-png/issues/340) and its not a problem with your file, you should probably not remove the gAMA chunk.

Comment: @kmdreko removing the bytes you mentioned worked, and opening the image worked. And thanks for the reference the the open issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce. This appears to be due to [a bug](https://github.com/image-rs/image-png/issues/340) introduced in the `png` crate version `0.17.4`. You don't have to manually manipulate the image and should instead simply use the previous version:

```toml
[dependencies]
image = "0.24.0"
png = "=0.17.3"
```